# Come si chiama la particella che indica la via o la piazza ecc. all'interno di un indirizzo?

Tags: grammar, nouns, particles

Se dico "Via Garibaldi, 1 - Roma" o "Lungarno Corsini, 10 - Firenze", "Roma" e "Firenze" si definiranno *località*, in seno all'indirizzo formulato, e "1" e "10" saranno i *numeri civici*; ma come si chiamano tecnicamente le parti che indicano la via, piazza, viale, corso, ripa, strada, discesa, eccetera?
E, in modo ancora più specifico, all'interno di quelle parti come si chiama la particella che indica il tipo di infrastruttura ("via", nell'esempio) e quella che ne indica il "titolare" ("Garibaldi")?

Comment: La risposta sta [qui](http://www.laputa.it/denominazioni-urbanistiche-generiche/). A Roma c'è una via che si chiama _clivo rutario_, dove _clivo_ significa _discesa_, ma 9 persone su 10 (inclusi gli agenti immobiliari) la chiamano _via Clivo Rutario_, perché non sanno cosa significhi _clivo_.

Comment: Tra le persone che non sanno cosa significhi _clivo_ ci devo mettere me stesso, perché, secondo la pagina che ho linkato, "è una strada in salita seguita da una discesa".

Comment: Devo fare ammenda per un mio precedente commento caustico a proposito del [sito relativo agli odonimi](http://www.laputa.it/denominazioni-urbanistiche-generiche) citato nel primo commento di @WalterTross: una prima impressione affrettata non era stata positiva, ma riguardandolo con più calma e scambiando qualche opinione con il responsabile di quella pagina, mi ricredo con piacere.

Answer (score 8):

Secondo questa [guida ufficiale delle Poste Italiane](http://www.poste.it/postali/cap/standard_composizione_indirizzi.pdf) la parte che contiene "via", "piazza", ecc... si chiama **qualificatore**. Non so cosa intendi quando parli di "titolare", visto che alcune vie si chiamano qualcosa come "Via Larga", "Viale dell'Università" o "Corso Bologna" e non c'è alcun titolare.

Answer (score 3):

La voce dell'*Enciclopedia dell'italiano* sugli [odonimi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/odonimi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) li chiama **appellativi**:

> Va osservato ancora che nelle denominazioni dell’area di circolazione, che sono ufficiali e fatte conoscere mediante tabelle, sono presenti numerosi appellativi (all’incirca 300 quelli reperibili attraverso l’Archivio Utenza Seat 2001): i più frequenti sono quelli del tipo *via*, *piazza*, ecc. ma numerosi rinviano a condizioni regionali o locali, talvolta in veste vicina al dialetto (Marcato 2005). Basti richiamare i veneziani *campo* e *campiello* per le piazzette, *calle* per le vie ...

Seguono altri esempi di appellativi di uso solo locale.